# Rename tab in MobaXterm for session duration

Tags: windows, unix, remote-access

How can we rename tabs in MobaXTerm for the entire session duration? At the moment, I can right-click and rename the tabs, but as soon as I press enter to get command prompt, MobaXTerm resets tab name to its original default. I have tried changing PS1 env variable with no effect. Please help.

Answer (score 10):

I haven't tried this myself but when you create a profile for a new ssh session, there is a tab "Bookmark settings" and within this tab there is a check box named "Lock terminal title." According to the manual:

Lock terminal title

Terminal title will be set to the session name

If you check this option, any attempt by the shell to set tab title will fail.
Uncheck this option if you want to allow the shell to change tab title.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I came across this and wanted to update it.

I found the answer here:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963545/rename-tab-in-mobaxterm-for-session-duration
```

I wrote a bash function to quickly handle this for me.

```
set_title() {
  PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -ne \"\033]0;$1\a\""
}
```

set_title "webserver"

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above works, just go to the sessions tab and click on the session you want to rename (just like when you want to rename a file). You should see the following:

[image]

After that, enter the preferred name and hit enter. The following window will occur:

[image]

Click yes and voilà!

**THIS IS NOT FOR THE SESSION DURATION BUT PERMANENT**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to open every new tab as a New Session (Click on the "Session" button) and then follow what ks2000 suggested (It works for me).

Answer (score 0):

There is limitation in number of sessions created for non-purchased mobaxterm. When you go for edit the session, red coloured message this message will be displayed. Delete unwanted sessions, unlock terminal title, then it will work. Otherwise purchase mobaxterm.